# PL/SQL Procedure/function with params to return a table from(of) a select query

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, procedure

how can a (Oracle)function/Procedure with parameters can be  created to return a table, which was returned by a select statement, inside a block

tried with refcursor
getting data as below ,all in a single row

{<G_ID=748,P_G_ID=746,P_NO=null,M_DATE=06-OCT-20 >,
<G_ID=749,P_G_ID=746,P_NO=null,M_DATE=06-OCT-20>} instead of a table format

[image link for the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeXsY.png)

P.S. I am pretty new to PL/SQL

Answer (score 1):

One option is to return refcursor. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select * from emp where deptno = par_deptno;
  7    return rc;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(10) from dual;
   
F_TEST(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81      10000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10


SQL>
```

Comment: - i have already tried This and absolutely works, but not sure all the data is coming in 1 cell instead of a table  for ex: {<GP_ID=123456,P_GP_ID=345632, .....>,< same continues>}

Comment: Cell? What cell? If you want to export data to e.g. MS Excel (which has "cells"), a simple option is to spool the result of a query into a CSV file - that's pure SQL. Or, if you want to use PL/SQL, you could concatenate column values and separate them with a semi-colon (or some other separator) and use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to display those rows. Or, use UTL_FILE package to create the output file. Or, use GUI tool (such as SQL Developer or TOAD) which offer export to Excel.

Comment: by cell i mean only one column...(only one row and one column) with this result in that .....{<GP_ID=123456,P_GP_ID=345632, .....>,< same continues>}. i am not referring to to any output file excel - thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying, sorry. If possible, provide an example - just like I did; edit the question and post it there.

Comment: {<G_ID=748,P_G_ID=746,PO_NO=null,M_DATE=06-OCT-20 >, ......
<G_ID=749,P_G_ID=746,PO_NO=null,M_DATE=06-OCT-20>}   this is how the response is displaying instead of a table format

Comment: Which tool do you use, so that it produces such an output?

Comment: You say your procedure is generating output incorrectly. Then you need to post that procedure along with test data an text - *no images*, table definitions (DDL)  and the **exact** output you want from that data. Please update your question and do not post this as a another comment.

Comment: @Littlefoot i am using sql developer with 12c and function what i have written is same as your example

Comment: @rajesh4ext In SQL Developer the entire cursor initially appears in one cell. To view the cursor as a table of data, double click on that cell.

Comment: @JonHeller - no it did not work , updated the query with the output image it says 1 row ....

Comment: On the right hand side, at its far end, the line that displays data, you'll see a *pencil* **icon**. Click it. It'll display the output nicely.

Comment: @Littlefoot  ,i did not find any pencil icon, are there any settings or can you please share a snapshot _

Comment: Which SQL Developer version do you use? I have 20.2. Should you upgrade?